# cURL very slow, possible to speed up

Tags: php, curl

Have a php curl request script below with a lot of requests which probably slows the code quite a lot, takes 1-2 minutes to load. Looked into curl_multi_execute but can't find a working solution. Any support much appreciated

```
$curl = curl_init();
 $options = array(
  'Access-Token: '. ACCESS_TOKEN .'',
  'Client-Secret: '. CLIENT_SECRET .'',
  'Content-Type: '. CONTENT_TYPE .'',
  'Accept: '. ACCEPTS .''
 );
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $options);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $requestMethod);

 $cyfin=$row['CYfin'];


 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, ENDPOINT . "accounts");
 $data = json_decode(curl_exec($curl),true);

 $curl2 = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $options);
 curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);


 for ($x = 1; $x <= $data['MetaInformation']['@TotalPages']; $x++) {
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, ENDPOINT . 'accounts/?page='.$x);

     $data2 = json_decode(curl_exec($curl),true); 
     foreach ($data2["Accounts"] as $i => $account) {

         if($account["Active"] = 1){ 
             $accountnumber = $account["Number"]; 
             $accountname = $account["Description"];

             curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_URL,ENDPOINT . 'accounts/'.$accountnumber.'?financialyeardate='.$row['CYfin']);
             $data2 = json_decode(curl_exec($curl2),true); 

             print_r($data2);
        } 
    }

}
 curl_close($curl);
 curl_close($curl2);
```